# Property set in ngOnInit results in "type error: this.student is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

EDIT: The code I've posted here works fine as I originally wrote it. I had a dumb typo in my student interface so the value "ID" was always undefined for each student object. I'm mad it took me days to realize this. Thank you for your answers everyone.

I'm currently learning Angular and am having an issue setting a property in a component's OnInit method. I'm using a service component to grab data from a json file and assign it to an instance of a custom interface called "student".

When grabbing all the student data in the form of an array to display in a table, everything works perfectly. However, when attempting to only grab the information of one student to display on a "detail" template, I get a "TypeError: _co.student is undefined".

Adding "*ngIf='student'" to the template eliminates the error message, but leaves the template unpopulated.

Here is the function to grab the data as defined in the service component

```js
private studentURL = 'assets/college-apps.json';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    getStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {
        return this.http.get<Student[]>(this.studentURL);
    }

    getStudent(id: number): Observable<Student> {
        return this.getStudents().pipe(map(students => students.find(student => student.ID === id)));
    }
```

And here is the ngOnInit method in the student-detail component

```js
student: Student;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private studentService: StudentService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

        this.studentService.getStudent(id).subscribe(
            student => this.student = student
        )
    }
```

And here is the template

```html
<mat-card *ngIf='student'>
    <mat-card-title>{{student.firstName}} {{student.lastName}}'s Details</mat-card-title>

    <mat-card-content let stude>First Name: {{student.firstName}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>Last Name: {{student.lastName}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>High School: {{student.highSchool}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>GPA: {{student.gpa}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>Reading SAT Score: {{student.readingSatScore}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>Math SAT Score: {{student.mathSatScore}} </mat-card-content>

    <a mat-stroked-button [routerLink]="['']">Back</a>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Were you able to debug and check that it is indeed returning a `student` from your `getStudent` call? This call is async, so at first your `student` will be undefined, so your `ngIf` is correct, but, if after the call returns your `student` is not populated, it may mean that it is returning `undefined`.

Comment: Console logging the this.student after getStudent shows this.student as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

since `this.student` is assigned in an async callback (in subscribe) when the template gets rendered first time `this.student` is undefined. when the http call returns a value it is `this.student` gets a value, until then while angular is trying to render template it will produce undefined errors. to workaround such cases angular possess an operator called [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths).

> The Angular safe navigation operator, ?, guards against null and
>   undefined values in property paths in templates.

```html
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>{{student?.firstName}} {{student?.lastName}}'s Details</mat-card-title>

    <mat-card-content>First Name: {{student?.firstName}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>Last Name: {{student?.lastName}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>High School: {{student?.highSchool}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>GPA: {{student?.gpa}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>Reading SAT Score: {{student?.readingSatScore}} </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>Math SAT Score: {{student?.mathSatScore}} </mat-card-content>

    <a mat-stroked-button [routerLink]="['']">Back</a>
</mat-card>
```

here is a simple demonstration of the concept https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gem5sk

try to remove one of the `?` in template and you will see undefined errors in console.

also be aware that until http call completes and a value assigns to `this.student` relevant places in template will be empty which may be a bad user experience especially for long lasting http calls. for that some kind of loader mechanism must be encompassed within application, but this is remotely related to this question. writing here just for side information.

also place the `console.log` withing async block to correctly see whether a value is returned from http call or not

```js
ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.studentService.getStudent(id).subscribe(student => {
         this.student = student
         console.log(this.student); // prints when the request completes
    });
    console.log(this.student); // always prints undefined, and gets printed before above console.log
}
```

Comment: Using either "?" or "ngIf" in the template removes the error messages, but leaves me with an empty page. The console log inside of the subscribe does return second, however it returns undefined just like the other console log.

Comment: `this.studentService.getStudent(id)` either doesn't return a value or returns undefined. probably `id` passed to `getStudent(id)` doesn't exist at all and `students.find(student => student.ID === id)` returns `undefined`. the problem is in `studentService` or backend. check your network logs

Comment: make sure that in here `let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');` there is a valid `id`

Comment: id seems to be passed properly. I'll keep looking into if studentService is doing everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try renaming your class variable to `student$` ($ indicates async value)
And change your `mat-card` tag the following:

```
<mat-card *ngIf="student$ | async as student>
  ... 
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have two issues:

1) `student` is undefined initially, and this causes an error.

You correctly fixed this by adding `*ngIf="student"` to your template, but then ran into the second issue.

2) Your page is not updated with the latest value.

This happens because you're NOT setting `this.student` inside `ngOnInit`, you're setting it from a *callback* that occurs sometime later (specifically, after the network request completes). Since this code happens at an "unknown" time, Angular is not notified that the data has changed and the view needs to be re-built.

So, you just need to manually notify Angular that "hey, something changed":

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";

[...]

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
            private router: Router, 
            private studentService: StudentService,
            private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    // Start network request
    this.studentService.getStudent(id).subscribe(
        student => {
            // Run after the request is completed
            this.student = student;
            console.log(this.student);
            this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
        }
    );
    // Run immediately after starting the network request
    console.log(this.student); // Undefined because the request hasn't completed yet
}
```

Comment: I've made those changes, but am still getting "undefined" on both console logs. Does this mean there is an issue with the getStudent method returning the data properly?

Comment: It really shouldn't be necessary to manually invoke change detection as that should be integrated into the HTTP mechanism. Unless he has enabled `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: there is no need to invoke CD manually unless CD is completely disabled for the component. as explained in [this article](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4) async events triggers automatic change detection.